# No colors in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, vim, terminal.app

Somehow my colors in Terminal.app are completely borked. If I load up Vim with syntax on, there are no colors, but line numbers are underlined (and so are some other parts).  It looks really really ugly. I can confirm that it's Terminal.app and not vim, because if I load up xterm it looks fine.

I have tried to restore defaults in preferences but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe you could try trashing `com.apple.Terminal.plist` from `~/Library/Preferences`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Make sure your $TERM environmental variable is correct.

Comment: Thanks @Heptite. When I type $TERM it says: bash: xterm-256color: command not found

Comment: Thank you so much @Heptite, changing the terminal to xterm-color in Preferences fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your $TERM environmental variable is correct. You can check it by doing:

```
echo $TERM
```